# What's the name of this folder?

Tags: lyx

See. I opened the LyX program. At the same time, in the folder listed in the Tools of Settings, the Time catalog creates a folder in the text box, for example, with the same name: lyx'tmpdir.gq1336. Tell me, please, is there a common name for this type of folder?

Comment: The `tmpdir` part of the name seems to indicate that this is a temporary folder (dir=directory=folder), or is that not what you mean by 'type of folder'?

Comment: I mean, that's what it is. So the name of the *Temporary Folder* is appropriate? Have you seen these folders yourself?

Comment: I'm not a LyX user so I have not seen this specifically, also I'm not really sure what you mean with 'a folder in the text box', is it visible in the interface somewhere? Maybe you can post a screenshot? Anyway, it is very common for programs to create temporary files and folders (not just LyX, many other programs do that too), that is normally not a problem.

Comment: Screenshot here: https://postimg.cc/64JZKnL5. you please sorry for the Russian language interface. It doesn't cause me any problems, I just write a blog in Russian language about this program and the problem was that I did not know in this blog how to call this folder, Well, in my opinion, this problem has already been solved in this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. When I put временный каталог in Google Translate it also says "temporary directory".

Comment: Well, with an interpreter, that's understandable. I have in LyX itself, as you can see in the screenshot, there is such a name. I just thought it was a different name. So, well, let's say I created a new .lyx file, opened it several times, made changes, closed it with the preservation of changes. At the same time, the corresponding time catalogue gradually accumulates a few sub-sappes. Tell me, please, what would you call each of these sub-cigarettes?

Comment: In general you can just ignore those folders and files. When LyX makes PDFs it doesn't do that directly from the `.lyx` file, it creates a temporary LaTeX source file, which is what you see. LaTeX itself creates various temporary files when the PDF is built, so you'd usually get multiple files, not just a `.tex` file.

Comment: How can I ignore these folders if I'm blogging about this program? In particular, I'll need some general name for these folders when I tell you how to use Asymptote in LyX.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: I think most users can ignore those folders, they never have to interact with them. But anyways, as has been said above, calling it what it is, i.e. "temporary folder" seems like a good option.

Comment: (By the way, when replying to a specific user, it's best if you write an at-sign followed by the username, e.g. @mathem. You as the owner of the post is always notified of new comments, everyone else is not, unless tagged like that. Only one user per comment can be tagged, and only other commenters or users who have edited the post can be tagged.)

Comment: @Torbj'rn T, with a temporary folder everything is clear. Here's a look, please, screenshot: https://postimg.cc/dh00VyQ8/f24dfda7. What kind of name can I use for, for example, a folder of lyx'tmpbuf2, so that By that name I could distinguish from the folder lyx'tmpbuf1, named by its respective household name and from the temporary catalog folder? For example. In this case, the Temporary Directory is the name of the folder lyx'tmpdir.gq1056

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment until now. (Use tab-completion of the username, then it'll be correct.) I don't really understand what you mean. All those `tmpbuf` folders are different temporary folders, probably corresponding to different LyX files.

Comment: @Torbjørn T, this applies to one LyX file: https://postimg.cc/qzkPcDws

Comment: So I still don't understand  what you're wondering about. When you make a PDF, LyX will create a `.tex` file in one of those temporary folders, and run `pdflatex` (or whatever you're using) on that file in that folder. What more do you need?

Comment: @Torbjørn T, please tell me, I understand correctly that in the case given in the last photo, I can call the folder lyx'tmpdir.gq2948 a temporary catalog, and the folders lyx'tmpbuf0, lyx'tmpbuf1, lyx'tmpbuf2 I can call the temporary catalog0, the temporary catalog1, temporary catalog2, respectively (with numbers)?

Comment: I do not understand why you feel like you need to do that, but if it's useful for whatever you're doing, go ahead ...

Comment: @Torbjørn T, when the same .lyx file opens several times, changes, and preserves, in your terminology, several time directories (and remains) (feel the confusion already occurred at this stage?). However, it may be necessary to name a specific folder on the blog. Here, for example, in one place I will say that something must be done in the temporary catalog, implying a folder lyx'tmpdir.gq2948, in another place I will say that something must be done in the temporary catalog, while implying a folder lyx'tmpdir1.

Comment: And it turns out that I named two different folders by one name (temporary catalog). And how then to distinguish these 2 folders when you write on a blog for the reader's who still has no idea about such details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99826/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-mathem).

Comment: Actually, I do not see a reason to continue the discussion, I believe that I have already received help. Thank you all.